# TaxCalculation (applicationContext.xml)

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to inlcude tax calculation on the site that I am building and I want to use the out of the box *SimpleTaxProvider*

I am trying to follow this link

https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/pricing/tax/simple-tax-provider#

I have to include the bean definition within my Spring application context file

This may be a noob question but I am confused. Where I am supposed to find this file?

*EDIT:
I understand that I have to do an annotation based configuration but it is not clear to me how

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

solved by one of the contributors at github:
https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite/issues/45

I am posting a solution here for anyone interested:

```
@Configuration
public class MyTaxConfiguration {

    @Merge("blTaxProviders")
    public List<?> myTaxProviders(SimpleTaxProvider blSimpleTaxProvider) {
        //merge
        return Arrays.asList(blSimpleTaxProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleTaxProvider blSimpleTaxProvider(){
        SimpleTaxProvider smpl=new SimpleTaxProvider(); 
        Map<String,Double> map= new HashMap();
        map.put("SPAIN", 0.08); //example1
        map.put("US", 0.1); //example2
        map.put("FRANCE", 0.2); //example3
        smpl.setItemCountryTaxRateMap(map);
        return  smpl;
    }



}
```